# Dynamics Nav 2009 R2: Update Page list

Tags: dynamics-nav

I have a page (list type) which contains a Repeater-Group with my elements. Now I have a report which will change visible fields. After the button is pressed, I get the updated Record with rec.Findset, but I am unable to update the view.

CurrPage.Update is not working for me.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I am not sure why CurrPage.Update is not working. 
Closing and the opening the page is working for me: 
Code
CurrPage.Exit;
PAGE.RUNMODAL(12345,MyRec);

Answer (score 0):

As you write then currPAGE.Update would normally do the trick. In fact I just created a simple test to try it again. 
The code I was using in the onAction was:

```
CLEAR(UpdateCust);
UpdateCust.RUNMODAL;
CurrPage.UPDATE;
```

UpdateCust is a variable of the type report and the report contains a single dataitem of the same type as the page. And the page is a simple List type, with no ListParts.

So if it doesn't work for you, then that means if it doesn't work there is something you're forgetting. Either to say or to do! :) But you also mention that you're using rec.FINDSET, that should not be used.

And I guess that you did verify that it is actually updating the records.

/Erik